# How to delete a reccordset with a URL Link

Tags: php, mysql, recordset

Hello everyone and good day 
Iam trying to delete a recordset with a link,
 what iam trying to do is once you click on the link the php checks that the variable "video_tut_id" is set and then it deletes the current record.
Now that's the theory but in practice it dosent work , as you guys can see iam self thought 
I also want to keep the delete php on the same page as the link

```
      if (isset($_GET['video_tut_id'] )) {

   $video_tut_id = $_GET['video_tut_id'];
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM video_tutorials WHERE video_tut_id = '$video_tut_id'");}
?>
      <td><a href="insert_video.php?video_id=<?php echo $row_video_tuts_edit['video_tut_id']; ?>">Delete</a></td>
```

If i was not clear as my English is not the best i will be more than happy to clarify

---

i changed the code to this

```
<?php 
if ((isset($_GET['video_tut_id'])) && ($_GET['video_tut_id'] != "")) {
  $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM video_tutorials WHERE video_tut_id=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_GET['video_tut_id'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_webiceberg, $webiceberg);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $webiceberg) or die(mysql_error());

  $deleteGoTo = "insert_video.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $deleteGoTo .= (strpos($deleteGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $deleteGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $deleteGoTo));
}
?>
```

and i put in on a new page and now it works

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `echo mysql_error();` to find if there are any errors in the query itself.

But right now you should learn about sanitizing your input - anyone could type whatever they want in the URL and your server would run it, no questions asked. I can guarantee you that someone will use that to do bad stuff.

EDIT: Also, your link has `video_id=...`, but the script is looking for `video_tut_id=...`.

Comment: true indeed , are u reffering to mysql injection